# images with different sizes side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have 5 images and their width and height are different to each other.
I'm trying to put these 5 pictures side by side in the center and make sure so the height of every imags is the same. I have tried flex, grid, float and positions to make it as close as possible, but still, some images are some pixels heigher or lower while one picture is very small compared to other.

html.

```
<div class="container">
<img class="leagues" id="l1" src="assets/img/ligue1.png" alt="">
<img class="leagues" id="pl" src="assets/img/premierleague.png" alt="">
<img class="leagues" id="cl" src="assets/img/championsleague.png" alt="">
<img class="leagues" id="la" src="assets/img/laliga.png" alt="">
<img class="leagues" id="bl" src="assets/img/bundesliga.png" alt="">
</div>
```

css.

```
.leagues {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 160px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
left: 50%;
top: 50%;

}
```

If there are any tutorials or sites that would show how to put images with different sizes side by side and make the same height by using Grid or Flexbox, that would be nice.

Thank you.

EDIT:

cleaned up the CSS and it looks like this now.

```
.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.leagues {
height: 200px;
width: auto;
}
```

and here is the image of how it looks.
as you can see, "premier league" logo is much smaller than others and the ligue1 logo is 2-3px smaller than rest.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/piIz4.jpg

Comment: `.container{ display:flex}` instead `leagues ` https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Images have different size.Do you want to show images with equal height and width?(and center)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL,DR;** This is probably what you're looking for:

```css
.container > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.container {
  height: 160px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

---

Actual answer:

You need to specify which is the `height` all images should be displayed at. 
You might want to specify it using CSS or use either the shortest or the tallest image:

**Hardcode using CSS:**

```css
.container > img {
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x125" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x175" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="">
</div>
```

**Use the shortest image:**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  let height;
  $.each($('.container'), function(_i, container){
    $.each($('img', container), function (_i, img) {
      height = height
        ? Math.min(height, $(img).height())
        : $(img).height();
    });
    $.each($('img', container), function(_i, img){ $(img).height(height) });
  });
})
```

```css
.container > img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x125" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x175" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="">
</div>
```

**Use the tallest image:**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  let height;
  $.each($('.container'), function(_i, container){
    $.each($('img', container), function (_i, img) {
      height = height
        ? Math.max(height, $(img).height())
        : $(img).height();
    });
    $.each($('img', container), function(_i, img){ $(img).height(height) });
  });
})
```

```css
.container > img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x125" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x175" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="">
</div>
```

As you can see, as long as you specify the same height for all, and `width:auto` they will already be displayed beside one another and all you need to do is center the `.container` in its parent, by adding `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to `.container`'s parent.
Example:

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  let height;
  $.each($('.container'), function(_i, container){
    $.each($('img', container), function (_i, img) {
      height = height
        ? Math.min(height, $(img).height())
        : $(img).height();
    });
    $.each($('img', container), function(_i, img){ $(img).height(height) });
  });
})
```

```css
.container > img {
  width: auto;
}
.center-me {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="center-me">
  <div class="container"
    ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt=""
    ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x125" alt=""
    ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt=""
    ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x175" alt=""
    ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt=""
  ></div>
</div>
```

---

P.S: I used jQuery to get and set image's height as it's less verbose than vanilla. If anyone needs it, I can write the jQuery-less equivalent, but it seemed overkill here.

P.S 2: You might want to replace `.container` selector with a more specific one if you don't want all the images in each of your `.containers` get reduced or enlarged to the shortest or tallest one in that particular container. This applies to both JS and CSS.

---

Last, but not least, the height might as well be hard-coded on the parent element and that would require no JavaScript, pretty much like the first example:

```css
.container > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.container {
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x125" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x175" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I edited the css above and this is what the output looks like.
Ligue1 is 2-3pixels smaller than other images
Premier League is very small, even if the image is over 1000px, its like i cant zoom in that image or cover or fill it.
https://imgur.com/a/aS9UPth

Comment: Please provide a link to an example so I can look at the code that's actually applying. I can't debug a screenshot.

Comment: Hi,
Here is a link with code that actually applying.
https://jsfiddle.net/kbLqh3w2/

Comment: All images have a height of ***exactly*** `140px`. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6spe2k18/) - each image has a red top and bottom border.  ( I also removed the useless CSS and used a different technique to vertically center in body - but that's besides the point).

Comment: @DMT82, reload the fiddle above. I added some CSS to make it very easy to notice the image size on hover.

Comment: Interesting, but then again, the Premier League logo's height, the lion is much smaller than others. How then do i do it so the height fits like the rest of them? Is it something I do with Photoshop and remove the whitespaces from top and bottom of each image or is it some way to fill, cover the logo so the height is the same, even if every image is 140px in the container. I mean, even if it stretches it wouldnt be any problem, and thank you for helping me.

Comment: CSS does what you asked from it. If you want that all symbols to have same margin/padding, you'll need an image editor. The simplest way is probably to just crop the image exactly at the margins of each logo and save them as such, so you can control the padding using CSS (with a wrapper for each). And no, there is no way for CSS to parse the contents of an image and decide to crop it based on contents. For CSS it's just an object loading some pixels.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Will try to resize every image so they have the same height and remve all extra spaces inside the images and try again. Thank you once again.

Comment: After resized every images height equal to the smallest image, now everything fits.
Its weird that you cant put 2 images with different heights and widths side by side and crop, fill, cover the images to they fit the same height without using photoshop and crop every image so it fits.

Answer (score 1):

display:flex must be given to the parent element , and if you want them same height , you should set a value for height and let width to be auto , if total width of all images don't be bigger than their parent , they will be in a row .
see flex box tutorial on w3schools :

[CSS flex Property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_flex.asp) 
[CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I cleaned up the CSS and made it as you said and.
.container -> display:flex and justify-content: center.
.leagues -> height: 200px and width: auto
But still, one picture is 2-3 px smaller than others and another picture is very small. Like, it doesnt stretch or cover or fill.
here you can see how it looks. https://imgur.com/a/aS9UPth

Comment: when the height is a certain size and the width is auto , elements width will be set according to their height and the original picture . the original size of your pictures are not same so they will not have same width . if you insist the same size , you can also a set a value for width , this may reduce the quality of your images . you also can try cropping images in same size

Answer (score 0):

either make their height the same (changing the picture by cropping it) or giving them a specific height